# SED cmd to remove above line if particular value is found from the given ldif input

Tags: linux, sed

```
abc
def
hij
klm
hij
nop
hij
qrs
tuv
wxyz
```

eventhough value hij is present multiple times , if qrs is found i need to remove the only above line alone ( hij ). Need output as :

```
abc
def
hij
klm
hij
nop
qrs
tuv
wxyz
```

Comment: Do you need to remove ANY line coming before "qrs", or is it required that the line to delete should specifically contain "hij"?

Comment: Did any answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/qrs$/!P;D' file
```

Open a two line window.

If the second line ends in `qrs` do not print the first line.

Otherwise print first line.

For all lines, delete the first line and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sed -e ':loop; /^hij$/!b; N; /\nqrs$/!{P;s/.*\n//; b loop}; s/.*\n//' INPUTFILE
```

It should produce the desired output.

##### Explanation

- `:loop` : define looping label
- `/^hij$/!b` : while line != "hij", print and start new cycle
- `N` : (line == "hij"), append newline and next line of input
- `/\nqrs$/!` if input does not end in "\nqrs"

  - `P` : print previous line
  - `s/.*\n//` : delete previous line
  - `b loop` : re-examine current expression without fetching a new line of input
- `s/.*\n//` : (at this point we know that input == "hij\nqrs") strip previous line, autoprint and start new cycle.

With the following input:

```
abc
def
hij
klm
hij
nop
hij
hij
qrs
tuv
wxyz
```

... it should produce

```
abc
def
hij
klm
hij
nop
hij
qrs
tuv
wxyz
```

Tested under Debian 11 with GNU SED in posix mode.

Edited my answer to take into account Sundeep's remark (thanks).

Hope that helps.

Comment: no it is coming as $//' and unterminated `s' command while using the cmd.

Comment: @prasannakpechu what is your `sed` implementation? GNU/BSD/etc? Edit: your tag has linux/ubuntu and with GNU sed the command shown here shouldn't give an error

Comment: @Grobu, your solution could fail if `hij` is found in consecutive lines followed by `qrs`

Comment: @prasannakpechu did you copy/paste the SED command?  Don't use double quote.

Comment: @Sundeep ah, sorry, I understand now.  With two consecutive "hij" lines, the command fails.  Thanks for your remark!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```bash
$ sed -zE 's/\n/ /g; s/[^ ]+ (qrs)/\1/g; s/ /\n/g' file
abc
def
hij
klm
hij
nop
qrs
tuv
wxyz
```

- `-z`: treat input as a set of lines
- `-E`: enable extended regexp
- `s/\n/ /g;`: replace newlines with blank space
- `s/[^ ]+ (qrs)/\1/g;`: replace a non space chars followed by `qrs` with `qrs`
- `s/ /\n/g`: replace blank spaces with newlines